# Adding server start argument on WebLogic -DUseSunHttpHandler=true

Tags: java, arguments, weblogic

I would like to set `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` argument on WebLogic. I add this  argument in WebLogic console -> Environment -> Servers -> serverName -> Configuration -> ServerStart -> Arguments

[Configuration -> ServerStart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8qdX.png)

[Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra4Zt.png)

Then I restart server and AdminServer, but this arguments are ignored. Using `System.getenv("JAVA_OPTIONS");` gives me:

```
-Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader  -javaagent:C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server
```

But, when I edit the setDomainEnv.sh file, and add `export JAVA_OPTIONS=$JAVA_OPTIONS -DUseSunHttpHandler=true`, everything works as expected.

My question: How can I set `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` without editing any scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did it correctly by adding the new options to the server start tab. Unfortunately and unintuitively, the node manager service caches the server start tab parameters, you should restart that first, then restart the managed server.

(also, note that WebLogic checks for custom parameters in the setUserOverides and setUserOverridesLate scripts as per https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/START/overview.htm#GUID-8B78ABB1-20AB-41CB-AB50-0DE5CB3F7234 - that's also a good option for adding parameters without the node manager hassle)

Comment: In that case I created a bin/setUserOverrides.sh file as you suggested
`#!/bin/sh

JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -DUseSunHttpHandler=true"`

This works and satisfy me. Thanks Mark you help me a lot :)